# How to create media down-loader like whats app, telegram in Xamarin forms? and how to create whats app UI

Tags: xamarin, image-processing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am creating social application in `Xamarin.Forms` where I want to implement media downloader to download image and video. currently I am using `Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations` nuget  to load image.
how to create Whatsapp UI using xamarin forms for android and iOS?

I want to implement manual media download functionality with progress shown in images thumbnail like whatsapp, telegram mobile app.

```
var cachedImage = new CachedImage() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    WidthRequest = 300,
    HeightRequest = 300,
    CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
    DownsampleToViewSize = true,
    RetryCount = 0,
    RetryDelay = 250,
    TransparencyEnabled = false,
    LoadingPlaceholder = "loading.png",
    ErrorPlaceholder = "error.png",
    Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg"
};
```

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading
[image]
[image]
[image]

suggest any approach to achieve above functionality in `Xamarin.Forms` or `Xamarin.Android` or `Xamarin.iOS`.

Comment: BTW: FFImageLoading has `DownloadProgress` callback. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

@Sumeet what I understood is as below please correct me if I am wrong :-

There would be 4 options to app user as below :

1. If user selects auto download option... 
    Media in the app would get downloaded automatically when we open app,  or in the  background the media could get downloaded.
2. If user select download over WiFi option from user settings 
    Media would get downloaded once user gets connected to WiFi.
3. If user selects download media manually option from settings 
   App media should only get downloaded once user select particular media for download
4. If user selects do not download option 
    User will not be allowed to download the media contents in the app.

Comment: same kind of functionality i need to implement in xamarin forms

Answer (score 3):

For file downloading using Xamarin Forms there is a nice article by Damien Aicheh :

https://damienaicheh.github.io/xamarin/xamarin.forms/2018/07/10/download-a-file-with-progress-bar-in-xamarin-forms-en.html

For circular progress dialog you can refer this article by James Montemagno :
https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms-on-android/

You need to create your custom xaml where you place your loader on top of a view and update the UI based on the file downloaded progress.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true progress bar, you will likely need to take over the image download yourself and build a custom control. You *may* be able to extend or modify CachedImage, but not sure if they provide hooks into their stream downloader (which you would want to replace with one that reports progress).

Another option would be to just show a nice animation with something like this https://github.com/DanielCauser/XamarinFFImageLoadingAndLottie

Answer (score -1):

Found to create UI like Whats app and functionality using Xamarin Forms check below link 
https://github.com/egbakou/WhatsAppUI

and below link is for some good looking UI in Xamarin Forms for android and iOS

https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-goodlooking-UI